# UIWebview become blank white page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In my application I'm using an authentication from web to login to my app like this picture below:
[image]

And now I'm face with a problem that sometimes I login then logout and login again, the uiwebview show a blank white page like this:
[image]

I don't know what happened with it. Have someone get the same problem like this? And how can I fix it?
Here is the code:

```
- (void)loadWebView {

NSString *urlString = @"https://api.ewings.vn/dialog/SdkWebView/login/?";
urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"redirect_uri=sh%@://",[Soha sharedInstance].gameId]];
NSDictionary *defaultParam = [SHRequest addMoreParametersForSOAPAPIsFromParam:nil WithOldAPI:NO];
for (NSString *key in defaultParam.allKeys) {
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", key, [defaultParam objectForKey:key]]];
}
[self.loginWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

if([request.description containsString:@"access_token"]){

    NSString* accessToken = [request.description componentsSeparatedByString:@"access_token="][1];
    accessToken = [accessToken componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"][0];

    NSString *decoded = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL, (CFStringRef)accessToken, CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    [Soha sharedInstance].gameAccessToken = decoded;
    [[SHLoginModal sharedModal] getUserInfoWithBlock:^(NSDictionary *userInfo, NSError *error) {
        if (accessToken) {
            [self loginSuccessfully];
            self.loginWebview = nil;
        }

    }];

}

NSLog(@"request des : %@",[request URL]);
return YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
self.backButton.enabled = (self.loginWebview.canGoBack);
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
self.backButton.enabled = (self.loginWebview.canGoBack);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.loginWebview.delegate = self;

self.navigationView.backgroundColor = SHColorFromHEX(0x167AC6);
[self.navigationTitle setText:@"Login"];
[self.backButton addTarget:self.loginWebview
                    action:@selector(goBack)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[self loadWebView];
}
```

Comment: can you log the webview fail to load request method and see if the request failed to load? If yes, you can then try to figure out what cause the page failing to load.

Comment: @user_zp: I added the webview:didFailLoadWithError method then put a breakpoint on it and log for error. But its doesn't jump in. The webview still loaded without error.

Comment: try to put the loadWebView method call in viewWillAppear and see if it works? I guess maybe because the viewcontroller is loaded already so that viewDidLoad will not call again when you try to do login again.

Comment: @user_zp: Tried. But its doesn't work.